# The bot does not mention messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I read the `discord.py` documentation and wrote this code according to it, but it didn't work.

```py
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! \\nHost Latency: {round (client.latency \* 1000)} ms!'.format(ctx.message.author.mention))
    print(f'TalkBack atemping: Pong! \\nHost Latency: {round (client.latency \* 1000)} ms!' )
```

Comment: Why are you uisng `f-strings` _and_ `.format`? You only need one or the other.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work". Are you getting an error message? Or is it just not responding to your command?

Comment: yes is it not responding to command

Comment: If I put something other than `.format` gives an error

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like? Where do you define your `client`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please, can you provide a link to the documentation your have read and where this code is from? Add this information in your question with [edit].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! \nHost Latency: {round (client.latency * 1000)} ms! {(ctx.author.mention)}')
    print(f'TalkBack atemping: Pong! \nHost Latency: {round (client.latency * 1000)} ms!')
```

If anyone has a problem, use this method

Answer (score 1):

hey here the first problem:

why do you format a f string?!

```py
await ctx.send(f'Pong! \\nHost Latency: {round (client.latency \* 1000)} ms!'.format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

should rather be

```py
await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Pong! \nHost Latency: {round(client.latency * 1000)} ms!')
```

and the \ makes no sense you want a new line not a special character \ ... so make
in the operation you dont use * only * you dont want the character ...

and the format problem is that there is nothing that can be formated there is no empty {} ...

Answer (score -1):

Just get the authors ID and do

```
<@ctx.author.id>
```

Comment: Should I put this instead of `(ctx.message.author.mention)` ?